# Python pygame, moving an object

Tags: python, pygame, move

Ive been following a tutorial to learn pygame.
I have this code to move an object in pygame.

```
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    dist = 1 # distance moved in 1 frame, try changing it to 5
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # down key
        self.y += dist # move down
    elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # up key
        self.y -= dist # move up
    else:
        self.y = 0
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
        self.x += dist # move right
    elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
        self.x -= dist # move left
    else:
        self.x = 0
```

it works but it isn't very fluid due to the order of sequence. ie if i hold the left button the object will move to the left. if i then press the right button while also holding the left button it will continue to the left. however if i do the opposite of this(hold right toggle left) the object will momentarily go left. Any idea's about how I could get this behaviour to mirror on both sides ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're introducing the asymmetry yourself, by checking for right and left in a particular order independent of what was pressed before.

To behave symmetrically, decide what you want to do if both buttons are pressed now, depending on which ones were pressed before -- so you need to keep track of the latter as part of your program's state.

So initialize the set of left/right keys previously pressed to empty:

```
was_pressed = set()
```

then in your loop you can start with

```
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    if pygame.K_RIGHT in was_pressed:
        # the left one's the new one!
        self.x -= dist # move left
    elif pygame.K_LEFT in was_pressed:
        # the right one's the new one!
        self.x += dist # move right
    else:
        # both freshly pressed at once, what now?!
        pass  # assume e.g they "cancel each other out"
elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    was_pressed = {pygame.K_RIGHT}
    self.x += dist # move right
elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    was_pressed = {pygame.K_LEFT}
    self.x -= dist # move left
else:
    was_pressed = set()
```

and similarly for up and down, of course.  The core idea is that `was_pressed` has at most one of the two buttons (when both have been pressed for a while it remembers which one was pressed **first**) so you can deliberately decide "what now" if the second one is also pressed while holding down the first one -- the code above reflects the logic I think you want from the way you word your Q, but can of course be adjusted.

The key thing is to avoid asymmetry depending on order of checks if both or neither are pressed!

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not a good method for Pygame. `else` parts are unnecessary. You can catch keyboard events like this;

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.y -= dist
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.x -= dist
            .... #going on like this
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP: #when stop pressing the button
            #catch keyboard events however you want
```

Comment: this is how the code was written in the tutorial.
however it also has its own strange behaviour when two buttons are pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex. This definitely set me on the right path.
before the main program loop I put:

```
was_pressed=set()
```

and my code inside my main loop ended up as:

```
if(pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]) and (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]):
        if pygame.K_RIGHT in was_pressed:   # the left one's the new one!
            x_speed = -3               # move left
            print("right")
        elif pygame.K_LEFT in was_pressed:  # the right one's the new one!
            x_speed = 3                    # move right
            print("left")
        else:                               # both freshly pressed at once, what now?!
            print("pass")
            pass
    elif(pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]):
        was_pressed = {pygame.K_RIGHT}
        x_speed=3
        print("right2")
    elif(pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]):
        was_pressed = {pygame.K_LEFT}
        x_speed=-3
        print("left2")
    else:
        x_speed=0
```

I put print statements in there so I could easily figure out what was doing what. I changed the last else statement because it didnt stop the object from moving. Sometimes if I pressed two keys together I got a double bang of the 'left'or 'right' print, but 'pass' print never banged, so that can be commited out. woohoo, I learnt something today and its working as intended. :P